# Optional validation on field with mask

Tags: reactjs, typescript, yup

I'm using Yup to validate some form fields, and there's one specific field which has a custom mask which needs to be validated, but only if it's filled, if it's empty, not required at all.

Here's what I've been trying to do, having two fields `customerId` which is required and already works, and salesmanId which needs to be validated only when it's not empty.

I already tried removing the `required()`, but no effect.

```
import { formMessages } from '@constants';
import { isValid as isValidCpf } from '@fnando/cpf';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
    
export const validationSchema = Yup.object({
  customerId: Yup.string()
    .required(formMessages.requiredIdValidationMessage)
    .test(
      'customerId',
      formMessages.invalidIdValidationMessage,
      (value = '') => {
        return isValidCpf(value!);
      },
    ),

  // THIS ONE HAS TO BE OPTIONAL
  salesmanId: Yup.string().test(
    'salesmanId',
    formMessages.invalidIdValidationMessage,
    (value = '') => {
      return isValidCpf(value!);
    },
  ),
});



<TextField
  autoComplete="none"
  id="salesman-cpf"
  name="salesmanCpf"
  type="text"
  label="CPF Vendedor"
  value={values.salesmanCpf}
  onChange={(event) => {
    if (
      isValidCpfInput(event.target.value) &&
      event.target.value !== ''
    ) {
      handleChange(event);
    }
  }}
  onPaste={(event) =>
    handlePaste('salesmanCpf', 11, event, setFieldValue)
  }
  helperText={touched.salesmanCpf ? errors.salesmanCpf : ''}
  error={touched.salesmanCpf && Boolean(errors.salesmanCpf)}
  InputProps={{
    inputComponent: MaskedField,
    inputProps: {
      replacement: { _: /\d/ },
      mask: '___.___.___-__',
      'data-testid': 'input-salesman-cpf',
      autoComplete: 'none',
    },
  }}
  InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
  FormHelperTextProps={
    {
      'data-testid': 'input-salesmancpf-helper',
    } as InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>
  }
  fullWidth
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the issue here is that when your input is empty, its value is read as empty string, thus, yup is doing the validation.

Just use `nullable` from yup, which will stop executing the validation while the value is `null`, `undefined`, or an empty string.

The code should look something like this:

```js
import { formMessages } from '@constants';
import { isValid as isValidCpf } from '@fnando/cpf';
import * as Yup from 'yup';

export const validationSchema = Yup.object({
  customerId: Yup.string()
    .required(formMessages.requiredIdValidationMessage)
    .test(
      'customerId',
      formMessages.invalidIdValidationMessage,
      (value = '') => {
        return isValidCpf(value!);
      },
    ),

  salesmanId: Yup.string()
    .nullable(true)
    .test(
      'salesmanId',
      formMessages.invalidIdValidationMessage,
      (value) => {
        if (!value) return true;  // Skip validation if empty
        return isValidCpf(value!);
      },
    ),
});
```

Comment: For some reason, using this, if I insert a value on the field, I cannot erase it completely anymore

Comment: The nullable is just for allowing those values as valids, it shouldn't infer on how the input handles an erase input. At first sight, it looks like this could be an error of how you've implemented the input.

I suggest you to update the main post with the code of this input for better context.

Comment: Added JSX component, Alejandro

Comment: Assuming that the problem you mention is found when changing the value of the input (onChange), it seems that you are not executing the handler when the value is `''`, surely if you eliminate this condition your problem will be solved!